# Can I find out if the current user has access to a record without querying?

Tags: apex, sharing

I run a query from an apex class (with sharing), and I get no results I can be sure the user doesn't have permissions (if I know otherwise that the records do exist).

But can I get this information without running a query?

I was thinking of the <object_name>Share objects but I suppose they aren't created for manual and rule based sharing?

Edit: Why I want no query? Here's my real scenario. In a VF page displaying multiple records, I need to show an 'Edit' button against records for which the current user has edit permissions. My question should've been clearer; sincere apologies.

Comment: What _information_ are you trying to get? A guarantee (or count) of how many records the user has permission to view?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

To find out if a particular user has Edit access to a record, use the [UserRecordAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm) object. This object is available in API version 24.0 and later. You can use SOQL to query this object to find out if the user has edit access to the record in question.

```
SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess 
FROM UserRecordAccess 
WHERE UserId = [single ID] AND RecordId = [single ID]
```

If you want to check a batch of records you can use

```
SELECT RecordId 
FROM UserRecordAccess 
WHERE UserId=:UserInfo.getUserId() 
    AND HasReadAccess = true 
    AND RecordId IN :allRecordIds 
LIMIT 200
```

But make sure that allRecordIds is a LIST of IDs. It doesn't work if allRecordIds is a SET of IDs. I guess that's a bug.

Also, only a maximum amount of 200 recordIds can be checked in one query.

Comment: "But make sure that allRecordIds is a LIST of IDs. It doesn't work if allRecordIds is a SET of IDs. I guess that's a bug." - That line just ended my hair pulling session.

Answer (score 21):

Since API 30.0 you can query an object directly (see [Checking for Object Accessibility](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm)):

```
SELECT Id, Name, UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess, UserRecordAccess.HasTransferAccess, UserRecordAccess.MaxAccessLevel 
  FROM Account
```

It also works for custom object, but unfortunately it doesn't help myself since it doesn't seem to work for the Task object.

Comment: Check the answers that already have given and since there may be the accepted answer as well. Also it's good to check when the question has raised. BTW, it's good to help the community :)

Comment: It was meant as an expansion on the (perfectly acceptable) answer given. People looking for this issue might end up here (like I did) and might be interested in the API30 solution as well.

Comment: I think this is a far better approach (for those object types for which it works) than the selected best answer because you are not limited to 200 objects; we have tested this and know it works with at least 1000 objects (if not more). BTW, I believe this provides a compound answer based on both profile CRUD permissions and sharing rules, but if someone knows better I would be interested to hear.

Comment: have you been able to find some way to get it working for `Task`?

Answer (score 14):

There is [Checking for Object Accessibility](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_std_checking_accessibility.htm) that shows how to check for access at the object level.

In Visualforce:

```
{!$ObjectType.Account.accessible}
```

In Apex (see [Understanding Apex Describe Information](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm)):

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult accountDescribe = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
System.debug('accessible:' + accountDescribe.accessible);
```

Beyond that, I suspect if you want to check at a per record level you won't be able to avoid the query.

I'm not very familiar with how the [Apex managed sharing](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm) works, but from what I've read you would just be querying the related sharing object rather than the object in question.

Comment: I would agree that there is no way to check record accessibility without a query. Rather than querying the sharing, use a newer object: SELECT RecordId, MaxAccessLevel FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = [single ID] AND RecordId = [single ID]. You can see more about this object here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm

Comment: @DanielHoechst Can you put that as an answer. Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I wanted to avoid a query only because it'd throw a No rows for assignment exception..

Comment: @LVS Select into a list (rather than an object) and you won't get the 'no rows' exception.

Comment: @metadaddy yes I do that..more detail in the question's edit :)

Comment: This is by far the shortest and clearest answer out there. It does not work for me only because my team wants me to create a service rather than doing it this way but if you have no limitations, this is hands down the easiest path.

Comment: This doesn't work for per-object accessibility so is less useful when you consider sharing rules.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple programmatic ways of determining access. But a declarative method is to just click the Sharing button on the record and view the users who have access as well as why they have access by clicking the 'Why?' link?