# Unknown Error in Workbench while querying UserEntityAccess

Tags: apex, tooling-api, workbench, gack

Getting Unknown Exception while querying 'UserEntityAccess' in work bench,

Query :

```
SELECT
    EntityDefinition.Id,EntityDefinition.DurableId,
    EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName, EntityDefinition.MasterLabel
FROM UserEntityAccess
WHERE UserId='xxxxxxxxU75'
AND EntityDefinition.qualifiedApiName= 'xx__c'
```

URL :

> /services/data/v36.0/query?q=SELECT+EntityDefinition.Id,EntityDefinition.DurableId,EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName,EntityDefinition.MasterLabel+FROM+UserEntityAccess+WHERE+UserId='xxxxxxxxxxU75'+and+EntityDefinition.qualifiedApiName=+'xx__c'

Comment: try to execute same query in developer console, doing so  You will get the error code, and then contact salesforce support .

Comment: yes I am getting the errorID but am I doing the correct thing here?

Comment: definitely something is incorrect, since you are getting error id, I believe it is very difficult to tell whats wrong here

Comment: I reproduced it. Got back the GACK Error ID: 481405300-62604 (-1680970010)
Do you have Premier support to raise it as a case?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you can't use `EntityDefinition` in the SOQL where clause like that against [UserEntityAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_userentityaccess.htm).

From the linked docs:

**Field**
EntityDefinition

**Details - Description**
The entity definition for the object associated with this user entity access record. *Because this field represents a relationship, use only in subqueries*.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. I tried using DurableID field on the UserEntityAccess object itself instead of durableId on EntityDefinition. But I don't know why even that is not woking.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to query, what level of access a user has to a particular object, using either UserEntityAccess or any other object? And I saw durableId on UserEntityAccess is using some pattern like <i>APIName.entityDefinitionDurableID</i>. Do you know what is that pattern and how to query that.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy Typically you would check the level of access for an individual record id or a set of record ids. See [Can I find out if the current user has access to a record without querying?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/191/102)

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy You can also reverse how the query is down from v30.0 onwards. `SELECT Id, Name, UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess, UserRecordAccess.HasTransferAccess, UserRecordAccess.MaxAccessLevel
FROM Account`

Comment: Hi Daniel. To much surprise query in my question is running fine today, I don't know how. But thanks a lot for your help. And my requirement is like, a super user wants to see all the users and their access level to a perticular object. So I think using UserEntityAccess will only help me.